# How do I create a new Window in electron js such that the original window is unusable until i close the new window?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I have tried creating a new Window but this allows the user to minimise the new window that's created and work with the original code. It creates a new Window when the user click on 'Settings'.
I will attach my code snippet down here:

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="" class="brand-logo center">Elderly Healthcare System</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="left hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a onclick= "newWindow()" href="#">Settings</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here is the function newWindow()

```
function newWindow(){
  window.open('settings.html',"","height = 300,width = 300")
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for the term "Modal".

Comment: Don't open a new window; instead display an overlay `<div>` (to catch clicks outside the "popup") and a `<settings>` div (the actual popup/dialog/modal). Use an `<iframe>` to show a separate document.

Comment: If you insist to not solve it inside html world see [this](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/window-open#using-chromes-windowopen-implementation): "The creation of the BrowserWindow is customizable via WebContents's new-window event."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Modal - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

And to disable background click or force user to click button on popup yo need to use **static** keyword.

If you opening the modal by js use:

```
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false})
```

Or though HTML

```
<button data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
Launch demo modal </button>
```